# loading levels / sections from menu

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to develop an app which will have a main menu that will contain a collection of buttons. Each button belongs to certain section of the app or in other words like a level in a game. I'm planning out the app before starting the code and first came to my mind is Storyboards. However, if i have too many levels, it wouldn't be practical to do it on Storyboard (think DLC). So i was thinking if there is a way for example load levels from a file such as plist. it's my first app with such style and i can't find the best way to do it. I'm looking forward for maybe let the user download extra content from the web rather than sending updates. so any idea on how can i achieve this? tutorials and links will be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

If you put your configurations in plist, you will need firstly read the configurations from plist, then manually create all those buttons and view controllers. Storyboards are more for static/known controllers you want to create. From my experience on IOS, unless your views and controllers are really standard and not too many customisations, it is really hard to update it just from the web and dynamic create view controllers.

There is actually a library that might fit for your needs. It is original used for form creation and updating. And it supports read configuration file and update the content. However, ignore it if it is not what you want. [quickdialog](http://escoz.com/open-source/quickdialog)